# DBA_OBJECTS vs ALL_OBJECTS

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration, plsql-package

I have created one package in my schema.
I am able to see the new package under the all_objects but dba_object is not giving any result.

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='UT_AIP_FX_AGGREGATED_ORDER_PKG';
-- No row fetched.

SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='UT_AIP_FX_AGGREGATED_ORDER_PKG';
-- giving the result.
```

according to dba_objects definition my 1st query also should return the result ?

I am using below oracle version.
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: Are you running both queries as the same user - just wondering if, while changing user, you're also changing from PDB to CDB?

Comment: yes i am running both the query from same user.

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, I am running both the query from same user and in same session.